# (object Object) being returned as output of onclick function in JQuery when using EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

So I have a JQuery function that on click of the current input element will change the value of the button. However, I need to be able to get the value of the objects in the li element, denoted by `<%= chats[i].msg %>`, so I can update my database with the respective data. However on a console.log of the object it keeps returning [object Object]. Is there any way for me to get the data? I'm new to JQuery and EJS so please point me to any duplicates.

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').on('submit', function(){ // hit submit

      var item = $('form input');
      var chat = {msg: item.val(), likes: ''}; //intially the post will have 0 likes

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: chat,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
          console.log(chat);
          console.log('success! yes'); 
          location.reload();
        }
      });
      return false;

  });
  $('.likebutton').on('click', function(){ // hit like
    console.log("like clicked?"); // works
    // i need to find a way to connect this with code and make it update???

    var curr = $('.display').val();
    var item = $(this).val('Liked'); // selects approatiate like button
    console.log("item: " + item); // return [object Object]?????  
    $.ajax({ //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/',
      success: function(err){
        // here we will get the data, find it in the data base and update it. Changes will occur 
        // via a reload, either manually or when they create a post, for now. Later we can update 
        // the thing in real time.

        // on click we must also change the color of the thing too to show that it was liked
        console.log('success!'); 
      }
    });
      return false;

    });

});
```

EJS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/assets/chat.js"></script>    
    <body>
        <h1> Ut whispers</h1>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder = "say something" name="msg"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <% for(var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) { %>
            <li class = "display"><%= chats[i].msg %> <input type="button" id = "changeit" class = "likebutton" value = "Like: (<%=chats[i].likes%>)" >
                <ul>
                    <li>replies will go here</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do console.log(“item: “, item), with a comma, plus sign tries to concatenate the object as a string

Comment: Not sure why that value is an object there though

Comment: Oh, its an object cause you’re setting it with .val(‘liked’) you want .val()

Comment: So I tried it with the comma, and I got this ```r.fn.init [input#changeit.likebutton] ```

Comment: Change to var item = $(this).val();

Comment: The way you have it you’re using it as a setter setting the value, you want the getter version of that call .val()

Comment: This was it! thank you so much!!!